# How to test the maximum load of a bulk emailing web application?

Tags: performance-testing, load-testing

I have to test a bulk emailing website (like MailChimp). I am a manual tester. Now how can I perform a performance test so that I can know when the website will be crash/down ?

Answer (score 0):

Web applications performance testing basically assumes simulating **normal** usage of the website by real users. The overall process should look something like:

1. Consider one of the load testing tools. If you don't have a corporate standard or ready solution there is [quite a number of free and open source load testing tools](http://www.opensourcetesting.org/category/testing-tools-overview/performance/?menu-page=overview). If you are uncertain which one to choose check out [Open Source Load Testing Tools: Which One Should You Use?](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/open-source-load-testing-tools-which-one-should-you-use) article which describes and compares the most popular and advanced solutions which are currently available.
2. The majority of load testing tools come with record-and-replay functionality so the next step would be recording your use cases / test scenarios to build up a load test "skeleton"
3. After that most probably you will need to perform [correlation](http://www.testingperformance.org/performance-articles/correlation) - the process of identifying dynamic parameters, cookies, headers, etc. and handling them by extracting changing parts from the previous response and replacing recorded hard-coded values
4. Normally you will also require [parameterization](http://www.geekinterview.com/question_details/14114), i.e. configure your test to use different credentials for different virtual users.
5. Once your test is ready you can run it with 1-2 users and iterations and inspect request and response details to ensure that your test works as expected.
6. When you're happy with your test behavior you can start **gradually* adding more and more virtual users unless response time exceeds acceptable maximum or errors start occurring or website crashes, whatever comes the first.
7. When you discover the maximum amount of virtual users and collect associated [performance metrics](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207420665-Performance-Metrics-for-Websites) it would also be good to identify the [bottleneck](http://www.performancetestingfun.com/bottlenecks/)

Comment: Agree with everything Dmitri writes, and if you're looking for a tool, I have also written an extensive review article comparing 11 different open source load testing tools, available here: http://blog.loadimpact.com/open-source-load-testing-tool-review

Comment: Many Thanks . I am using Blazemeter now for basic test report . But I will call you guys whenever I need help

Answer (score 0):

You need to be very explicit about what you are testing.  Are you testing the scheduling engine?  Are you testing the SMTP relay?  Are you testing the SMTP relay with specific max out of spec conditions delays in connecting to a downstream relay?  Are you testing re-queues before your SMTP throughput drops to zero? It makes a significant difference in your test setup.

Also, it would be worthwhile for you to read the RFCs on SMTP before this test.  Email is designed to be resilient across less-than-perfect connections, but this would result in a slowed SMTP relay over time.

< soapbox >

Also, as a manual tester you should never be asked to do this by your management unless they have committed to your training and a mentor to assist you in the effort.   Any other path and they are interested in a check box or billing, but not a reduction in risk

< /soapbox >

Comment: Very clear answer. Thank You. However I have some confusion yet. So I let you know whenever I need help